# When trying to mount an E01 image in terminal using ewfmount, it says "Unable to create fuse channel". What do you think is the problem

Tags: command-line

This is the image of the problem I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: Is this Ubuntu? If not, you need to ask the question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to mount to a non-empty folder. If you create a folder within your /mnt folder (i.e. /mnt/e01Raw/), then you should be able to run ewfmount and get the raw stream.

sudo mkdir /mnt/e01Raw 
sudo ewfmount CFReDS001.EO1 /mnt/e01Raw